# In point-blank range, is Winston's melee preferable to his gun?

Tags: overwatch

Winston's LBM weapon, the "Tesla Cannon", has a greater range than melee and can hit multiple enemies at once. However, if I'm fighting just one enemy and I manage to get within melee range of them, is it better to use melee attacks, or is the cannon still preferable?

I'm asking because although I'm having a blast playing him, I feel his damage is underwhelming, and I wonder whether going with melee attacks is the way to go if I can get the enemy within range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Melee attack does [30 *damage*](http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/March_17,_2016_(beta)) and Winston's Tesla does [60 *DPS*](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Winston)

A melee attack takes [one second](http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/March_17,_2016_(beta)), so no, it's not better to use melee - stick with the gun.

Comment: Do you have  a more recent source for Melee damage? The one you linked is 7 months old, and a *lot* has changed between then and now.

Comment: @Wipqozn Updated with 2 month old link.

Comment: Melee does 30 damage, not 50.

Comment: I just tested this in-game and the damage with Genji seemed to be  abit higher than 25. I believe the newer link you posted was still outdated, since it's from before the newest beta. There were a lot of changes between the final beta and the previous ones, so melee damage was likely modified.

Comment: unless your out of ammo, it that case melee is better

Answer (score 3):

It's better to use both.

As Иво Недев noted, the Tesla Cannon does more damage per second than a melee attack, however it is very unlikely that you fight an opponent with only 60 HP.

By using Tesla Cannon and then melee hitting instead of reloading you could possibly finish off a low health enemy instead of having to reload (1.5 seconds of no damage), allowing you to maybe get that kill in faster.

Comment: I don't think this makes sense unless you can cancel the melee animation, which as far as I know is not possible.

Comment: Assuming you've just reloaded you can shoot 5 seconds at 60-65 hp, there are plenty of characters with more and that's assuming you hit everything and only fight 1 person at a time. Hitting in between means you have longer in between reloads and can pump out more damage in a single charge.

Comment: That's exactly the same as firing your gun until your ammo is fully depleted and then start punching, if we're talking about sustained DPS.

Comment: Given the animation length of the melee, Winston *does* do slightly more overall damage if he intersperses his primary fire with melees, but it's such a small increase that it's not practical because of the risk of missing your melee attack.